# How to pass value to web view web page in android studio?

Tags: android

I beginner in android studio and want to write simple application to open bank web site and fill the textbox with my value,on bank web site have a some text box to fill my data,for example this site:
[enter link description here](https://epayment3.bmi.ir/Remain)

and i want fill it automatic with my parameter.How can i do this?thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear . Could you rephrase it.

Comment: I guess the thing you have mentioned is not possible . But you can try creating your Custom Webview in this Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='your text';"; 
webview.loadUrl(javascript);
```

Use this method on **onPageFinished**

Comment: thanks my friend ,please dont clear your answer ,i want to test your answer,but now have work and should be go outdoor.